# Can't get setFieldValue to work

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

I've got this

```
    // Creating users through frontend
    Event::on(Users::class, Users::EVENT_BEFORE_ACTIVATE_USER, function(UserEvent $event) {
        $userId = $event->user->id;

        // Allow assigning user groups through the frontend (circumvent elevated user sessions)
        $groupId = Craft::$app->getRequest()->getBodyParam('userGroup');
        if ($groupId) {
            Craft::$app->getUsers()->assignUserToGroups($userId, [$groupId]);
        }

        // This does not work
        Craft::$app->users->getUserById($userId)->setFieldValue('discountPercentage', 15);
    });
```

Assigning the user group works fine, so I don't get why assigning a field value doesn't. The `discountPercentage` field is a simple Number fieldtype

I also tried `$event->user->setFieldValue('discountPercentage', 15);` without success.

Also I tried surrounding `15` in quotes, like `'15'`, but that didn't work either.

Edit:

Submitting the "create user form" through the frontend gives no errors. `discountPercentage` is just left blank.

Comment: Why the downvote? If there is a better way for me to ask for help, please tell me so I can improve. That would be constructive, rather than downvoting without explaining why. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are going to set the fieldValue, you need to save the element:

```
    $userObject = Craft::$app->users->getUserById($userId);
    $userObject->setFieldValue('discountPercentage', 15); 
    Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($userObject);
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: That works, the only exception being that I needed to remove `one()` when getting the `$userObject`. Thanks!

Comment: Good point @StianKarlsen; edited it appropriately...